# HttpClient with ResponseHeadersRead fails(timeouts) at 2nd GetAsync try without Fiddler(Http/Https debugger)

Tags: c#, https

I'm trying to get some page's status code.

Problem is default GetAsync method returns the whole page with content, while I only needed the header to check page's status(404,403, etc..), which will end up as hogging up the memory since I have to check tons of URIs.

I added ResponseHeadersRead option to solve that memory hogging issue, but then that code started to throw "A Task was cancelled" Exception, which means timeout.

Things that i know :

1. ResponseHeadersRead code ONLY works, when i runs fiddler(Http/Https Debugger) on my local PC.
2. ResponseHeadersRead code works at online-coding environment, like dotnetfiddle. but doesnt work on Windows OS Environment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


public class Program
{
    public static string[] Tags = { "first", "second" };
    public static string prefix = null;
    static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;

        // limit parallel thread
        Parallel.ForEach(Tags,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 1.0)) },
        tag =>
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        prefix = "1";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        prefix = "2";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        prefix = "3";
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(tag.ToString() + " and " + i);
                HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync("https://example.com/" + prefix).Result; // this works
//                HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync("https://example.com/" + prefix,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result; // this fails from 2nd try with one url.
                Console.WriteLine(i + " and " + (int)response.StatusCode);
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

It gets thread timeout with ResponseHeadersRead, while it isn't without it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Parallel` for `async` code, it is intended for CPU bound. You can run all the requests concurrently without wasting threads blocking on it. The way to solve this issue is not to increase `DefaultConnectionLimit`, however, this will solve it in this case. The correct way to deal with `ResponseHeadersRead` is to either `Dispose` the `response` i.e.

```
using(HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync("https://example.com/" + prefix, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result) {}
```

or to read the `Content` of the response.

```
var data = response.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

With `ResponseHeadersRead`, you need to do this in order for the connection to be closed. I would encourage you to rewrite this code to get rid of `Parallel` and not to call `.Result` on your `async` calls.

You can do something like this:

```
private static async Task Go()
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;

    var tasks = Tags.Select(tag =>
    {
        var requests = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    prefix = "1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    prefix = "2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    prefix = "3";
                    break;
            }

            requests.Add(MakeRequest(Client, prefix, tag));
        }
        return requests;
    }).SelectMany(t => t);

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async static Task MakeRequest(HttpClient client, string prefix, string tag)
{

    using (var response = await client.GetAsync("https://example.com/" + prefix, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tag + " and " + prefix);
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + " and " + (int)response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for both explanation and providing solution :)

Comment: "The correct way to deal with ResponseHeadersRead is to either Dispose the response or to read the Content of the response." Yes! Just got bit by this, using ResponseHeadersRead and returning the stream to the caller, expecting they would deserialize, but if they don't, the connection breaks and has to be re-established.

Answer (score 2):

When you set ResponseHeadersRead, you are instructing the HTTP client to read only the HTTP headers from each response, and so the TCP/IP connection on which the request is made is in the middle of the response until you read the response body.

And there's a [limit to how many connections HttpClient will open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections) to any particular web site.  This defaults to 2.  So you open two connections, and try to open a third, which blocks waiting for an available connection.

You can simply increase the connection limit for your application.

eg:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
```

Comment: But, that doesnt explain Client.GetAsync("https://example.com/" + prefix,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead) doesnt work while Optionless GetAsync does work w/o problem. am i missing something here? i dont think thats max connection limit issue.

Comment: Without the ResponseHeadersRead option GetAsync().Result reads the whole response body and Does not keep an open connection.  This allows the third request to connect.  Also I observed the behavior in a test program.  Try it yourself.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. do you also know why that code worked out when i turned on fiddler for debugging?

Comment: Fiddler is a local proxy server, so all your connections actually go to Fiddler.  Either ServicePointManager never limits connections to proxy servers, or doesn't limit connections to local IPs.  Or perhaps both.

Comment: Thanks so much, you demysfied my most thoughts.